# Run a large amount of regressions and storing coefficients

Tags: r, regression, panel

I am trying to run a large amount of regressions in my panel data. In this simple example its an univariate regression, but in reality i'm trying to run a multivariate regression (mentioning this just case).

My data looks like this:

| DATE | year | month | ASSET_CODE | RET | MKTRET |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | 2000 | 1 | 1 | -0.5 | 1 |
| 2000-01-01 | 2000 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000-01-02 | 2000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2000-01-02 | 2000 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2000-01-03 | 2000 | 1 | 1 | 0.3 | 3 |
| 2000-01-03 | 2000 | 1 | 2 | -0.2 | 3 |
| 2000-02-01 | 2000 | 2 | 1 | -3 | 4 |
| 2000-02-01 | 2000 | 2 | 2 | -1 | 4 |
| 2000-02-02 | 2000 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2000-02-02 | 2000 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2000-02-03 | 2000 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 2000-02-03 | 2000 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 6 |

I want to group by month and asset code and run a regression RET ~ MKTRET (in each month for each asset code) and store the coefficients for the slope and intercept, and nothing else. I want the end result to be formatted like this:

| year | month | ASSET_CODE | INTERCEPT | SLOPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 1 |  |  |
| 2000 | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 2000 | 2 | 1 |  |  |
| 2000 | 2 | 2 |  |  |

I tried the following approach, which should have given me a dataframe with all the necessary information (and a lot more, including other statistical info) which I could have used to reshape to get the end result:

```
regressions <- df %>%
  group_by(month, year, ASSET_CODE) %>%
  do(regressions_fit = lm(RET ~ MKTRET, data = ., na.rm = TRUE))
regressions_coef <- tidy(regressions, regressions_fit)
```

However, this approach did not work for me because I ran out of memory on my computer. I suspect it has to do with the fact that it stored ALL the information related to the regressions and not just the SLOPE and INTERCEPT which i am interested in. Is there a less resource-intensive way to do this?

Comment: Write a function to perform one of the regressions.  Give it two parameters: the first being the data frame to analyse.  The second can be anything (and can be ignored).  Call this `myFunc`.  Then `df %>% group_by(year, month, ASSET_CODE) %>% group_walk(myFunc)` should give you what you want.  Statistically, Fitting a single model to *all* your data, with terms for `month` and `ASSET_CODE` is likely to be more efficient (in the sense that you will have smaller confidence intervals for your parameters) and equally valid.

Comment: ... Interactions between the terms you are *really* interested in and `month` and `ASSET_CODE` may be useful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flm` in the collapse package is like `lm` but returns the coefficients only and is faster.  An alternative would be to use `coef(lm(...))` in place of `flm`.

```
library(collapse)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year, month, ASSET_CODE) %>%
  summarize(as.data.frame(t(flm(RET ~ MKTRET, cur_group()))), .groups = "drop")
## # A tibble: 4 × 5
##    year month ASSET_CODE `(Intercept)` MKTRET
##   <int> <int>      <int>         <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1  2000     1          1        -0.533  0.4  
## 2  2000     1          2         2.13  -0.600
## 3  2000     2          1       -12.2    2.5  
## 4  2000     2          2        -6.83   1.50
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form

```
df <- structure(list(DATE = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", 
"2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-02-01", "2000-02-01", 
"2000-02-02", "2000-02-02", "2000-02-03", "2000-02-03"), year = c(2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L), month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), ASSET_CODE = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), RET = c(-0.5, 1, 1, 2, 0.3, -0.2, -3, -1, 2, 1, 
2, 2), MKTRET = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach if it's better. It uses `Rfast::lmfit` which has not so much overhead like `lm` and is very fast.

```
res <- by(dat, dat[c(2, 1, 3)], \(x) {
  with(x, Rfast::lmfit(cbind(intercept=1, slope=MKTRET), RET)$be)  |>
    t() |> cbind(x[1, c(2, 1, 3)])
}) |> do.call(what='rbind')

res   
#     intercept slope month year ASSET_CODE
# 1  -0.5333333   0.4     1 2000          1
# 7 -12.1666667   2.5     2 2001          1
# 2   2.1333333  -0.6     1 2000          2
# 8  -6.8333333   1.5     2 2001          2
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), month = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), ASSET_CODE = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), RET = c(-0.5, 1, 1, 
2, 0.3, -0.2, -3, -1, 2, 1, 2, 2), MKTRET = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```